# Unusual airplane shown in Google Earth

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane

[image]

At first I thought it was a plane that had its wings removed for some reason.

[image]

Then I thought it might be a lifting body, but I don't think so. Any ideas? This was in Jacksonville, FL; I can provide the coordinates if needed.

[image]

Comment: Looks like an F-18 with the wings removed. Possibly fire dept training or similar.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE!

Comment: Agree with F/A-18, although with a modified radome. Coordinates could help; was this at the Naval Air Station or the international airport? If the former, perhaps trainer of some sort for maintenance technicians, maybe?

Comment: @Ralph - not "modified" radome...looks just cut off. Maintenance trainer? No, there's not enough of it left. In all my years of fighter maint (USAF), we just had regular fully functional jets cycle through.

Answer (score 16):

> [image]
>
> The United States Marine Corps is facing a dilemma. There are not enough combat ready fighter jets for their pilots around the world. Boeing's answer to this problem is **the C+ Program.** The program will take 30 retired F/A-18C Hornets and upgrade them to the most state-of-the-art platform, creating the F/A-18C+. ([boeing.com](http://www.boeing.com/features/2016/10/C-plus-Scores-A-plus-with-Marines_10_16.page), 2016, emphasis added)

Three years after that Boeing article, only three upgrades were completed. Given the slow pace, that's enough time for isolated airframes to be spotted as they're readied for transport and upgrades. The initial volume of 30 was reduced to 25 then 19, enough for one squadron ([seapowermagazine.org](https://seapowermagazine.org/navy-reduces-planned-f-a-18c-hornet-conversions/), 2019). The photo above ticks all the boxes: the missing and covered nose radome, covered canopy, and missing wings.

Comment: Nice find! Looks about like the same surroundings, too. Curious why the stantions & rope around it in the OP photos, though.

Comment: The jets are trucked from Davis-Monthan Air Force Base to Cecil Field near Jacksonville, Fla. http://www.boeing.com/features/2016/10/C-plus-Scores-A-plus-with-Marines_10_16.page

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it’s the remains of an old F/A-18 classic, with its wings and tailplane removed. It also looks like they removed a substantial amount of the fuselage as well as the engines, rudders and nose radome.  I’m guessing this photo was taken over NAS Jacksonville?